# Writing RationalNumber class in C++

Tags: c++

I need help with an assignment.
I am still new to all of this.
I am suppose to

Create a class RationalNumber (fractions) with these capabilities:

Create a constructor that prevents a 0 denominator in a fraction, reduces or simplifies fractions that are not in reduced form and avoids negative denominators.
Overload the addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division operators for this class.
Overload the relational and equality operators for this class.

I am having trouble getting my fractions to reduce properly when added together. For example if my first fraction is 1/3 and my second is also 1/3, the answer should come out to be 2/3. However ever time I run the program the answer comes out to be 2/1 no matter what fractions I put in.

Here is my RationalNumber header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//RationalNumber class
class RationalNumber
{
public:
    RationalNumber(); //constructor
    ~RationalNumber(); //destructor

    void retrieveInput();
    int GreatestCommonDenom(int num1, int remainder);
    void reduceFraction(int &num, int &denom);
    void operator+(RationalNumber o1);
    void operator-(RationalNumber o1);
    void operator*(RationalNumber o1);
    //void operator/(RationalNumber o1);

private:
    int num, denom;
};
```

Here is my RationalNumber functions:

```
#include "RationalNumber.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//RationalNumber Class Functions

RationalNumber::RationalNumber() //constructor
{
    //initializes objects
    num = 1;
    denom = 1;
}

RationalNumber::~RationalNumber() //destructor
{
    //de-allocates memory
} 

void RationalNumber::retrieveInput() //creates user fractions
{
    int num, denom;

    cout << "\nEnter a numerator: \n\n";
    cin >> num;
    cout << "\nEnter a denominator: \n\n";
    cin >> denom;
    cout << endl;

    //denominator
    while (denom == 0)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a denominator: \n\n";
        cin >> denom;
    }

    while (denom < 0)
    {
        num *= -1;
        denom *= -1;
    }

    cout << num << "/" << denom << endl;
}

int RationalNumber::GreatestCommonDenom(int num1, int remainder) //gets lowest common denominatior
{
    if (remainder == 0)
    {
        return(num1);
    }
    else
    {
        return(GreatestCommonDenom(remainder, num1%remainder));
    }
}

void RationalNumber::reduceFraction(int &num, int &denom) //reduces the fraction to its lowest form
{
    int reduceFrac = 0;
    if (denom > num)
    {
        reduceFrac = GreatestCommonDenom(denom, num);
    }
    else if (denom < num)
    {
    reduceFrac = GreatestCommonDenom(num, denom);
    }
    else
    {
        reduceFrac = GreatestCommonDenom(num, denom);
    }

    num /= reduceFrac;
    denom /= reduceFrac;
    cout << "After reduction, the answer is " << num << "/" << denom << endl;
}
void RationalNumber::operator+(RationalNumber o1) //adds the fractions
{
    RationalNumber temp;
    temp.num = (this -> num * o1.denom) + (o1.num * this -> denom);
    temp.denom = (this -> denom * o1.denom);
    reduceFraction(temp.num, temp.denom);
}
//void operator-(RationalNumber o1)
//{}
//void operator*(RationalNumber o1)
//{}
//void operator/(RationalNumber o1){}
```

And here is my main program so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "RationalNumber.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome!\n" << endl;
    cout << "Today we shall preform some math functions on fractions.\n" << endl;

    //create two objects
    RationalNumber frac1;
    RationalNumber frac2;

    //retrieve user input for their fractions
    cout << "Enter your first fraction: \n\n";
    frac1.retrieveInput(); 
    cout << "\nEnter your second fraction: \n\n";
    frac2.retrieveInput();

    //using this to see the output (only temporary)
    frac1.operator+(frac2);

    int answer;

    cout << "Menu" << endl;
    cout << "\nWhich would you like to preform on your fractions: \n" << endl;
    cout << "1: Addition\n" << endl;
    cout << "2: Subtraction\n" << endl;
    cout << "3: Multiplication\n" << endl;
    cout << "4: Division\n" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your option: \n" << endl;
    cin >> answer;

    return answer;


    switch (answer)
    {
    case 1:
        frac1.operator+(frac2);
        break;

    default:
        cout << "Invalid option." << endl;
    }

    cout << "\n" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I am also having some trouble with the switches in order to accomplish outputting the answer, but it pretty much closes the program afterwards so I have no idea what it is outputting. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a reduce function which was always called from a constructor:

```
RationalNumber::RationalNumber(int a, int b)
{
    // do error checking that denominator b is non-zero etc.

    this->a_ = a;
    this->b_ = b;
    reduce(this->a_, this->b_);
}
```

Then we all operators (like add) would create a new rational number using the constructor. Example of a naive reduce function could be (modify it to deal with negative numbers):

```
void reduce(int& a, int& b)
{
    int k = 2;
    while(k <= ((a <= b) ? a : b)){
        if(a%k == 0 && b%k == 0){
            a /= k;
            b /= k;
        }
        else
            ++k;
    }   
}
```

The point is to call it from the constructor to always have the rational number in its most reduced form. So an add function might look something like

```
RationalNumber RationalNumber::add(const RationalNumber& r) const
{
    return RationalNumber(this->a_ * r.b_ + this->b_ * r.a_, this->b_ * r.b_);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sidenote: If I were you, I would overload the operator so the method would be called RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator+(RationalNumber o1). This way when you add two rational numbers you can simply write

```
RationalNumber sum = frac1 + frac2
```

The reason this is happening because your code think its adding just 1/1 + 1/1 since this is what you set in the constructor. In retrieveInput(), you're intention is to set the numerator and denominator from the user input, however you never set the class member variables num and denom. You're only setting the local variables you create in that method leaving you still with 1/1 as the numerator and denominator of your member variables. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You have several instances in your code where you want to change some object, but don't actually do that.

As Josh stated, your retrieveInput function actually changes the local variables num and denom. You have class members num and denom, but with your statement `int num, denom;` you hide those member variables.

In your `+` operator you save the result of the addition in the temp object, which gets destroyed immediately afterwards and you don't return it.

Also, the `GreatestCommonDenom` function actually calculates the greatest common divisor, not the lowest common denominator.

Just think a little bit more about which objects you actually change and whether those are the ones you want to change.
Any time you write something of the form `type varname;` (like `int num,denom;` or `RationalNumber temp;` ) inside a function, the variable `varname` will be destroyed as soon as the function reaches the `}`

One more thing: From the sound of the assignment I would assume you are expected to write a constructor that takes two arguments instead of just being able to input values after the number is already created.